# Looking for something similar to Laravel Livewire for Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am looking to use Spring Boot for my next project and I am unable to find something that offers similar functionality to [Laravel Livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/), does anybody know if something like this exists?

Comment: I didnt know Livewire so I looked it up. First line in its doc says "Include the PHP". Im very serious when I ask this: do people really use PHP for new projects?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean? Laravel is a PHP framework...

Comment: @BossMan Sure why not?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf

Comment: @Simon Martinelli Thymeleaf is a templating engine. I am looking for something that effectively allows me to reactively make requests without requiring JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

oh you mean this one . [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/)

You are looking for a component-based architecture